# How can I populate a class based on an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of data that can have 1 to 10 values in it. Based on the number of values in the array I want to select 1 of 10 differnt classes and place the values of the array in the class object.

This is what I have so far,

```
Array[] ar;
ar = PopulateTheArray();
int cnt = ar.Count();
Object ob = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "MyObject" + cnt);
```

There are 10 MyObject classes like this,

```
public class MyObject1
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
}
public class MyObject2
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}
public class MyObject3
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
}
and so on.....
```

How do I loop threw the array to populate the object, since the object is created dynamically?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, or is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I wish it was homework, I don't yet have a firm grasp on building this dynamically or how to access them.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you want to do as there probably are other ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have data comming in from a web page, the data is an array. I need to select the correct class and pass it to the rest of my application. I simplified the code above for this question.

Comment: In a nutshell... I need to dynamically create an object, poputate it and pass it on.

Answer (score 1):

This class architecture really does look very strange. It appears that you have a *convention* that class `MyObjectX` will have exactly X properties named `Column1` - `ColumnX`. I've never seen that before, nor can I think of any scenario where that would be appropriate.

In any case, I would strongly suggest you describe your problem domain and your current architecture so that others might be able to evaluate its appropriateness and perhaps suggest alternatives. For example, it's *possible* that just need to write one class that encapsulates an array (or maybe some other collection):

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string[] Columns { get; private set;}

    public MyObject(int numColumns)
    {
        Columns = new string[numColumns];
    }   
}
```

---

But I will try to answer the question as asked.

You can do something like this:

```
object ob = ...
object[] ar = ...

for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
{
    ob.GetType().GetProperty("Column" + i).SetValue(ob, ar[i], null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you had an abstract base class?

```
public abstract class MyObjectBase
{
    public abstract void Initialize(params object[] args);
}
```

Then your example becomes:

```
public class MyObject1 : MyObjectBase
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public override void Initialize(params object[] args)
    {
        this.Column1 = args[0];
    }
}
public class MyObject2 : MyObjectBase
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public override void Initialize(params object[] args)
    {
        this.Column1 = args[0];
        this.Column2 = args[1];
    }
}
public class MyObject3 : MyObjectBase
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public override void Initialize(params object[] args)
    {
        this.Column1 = args[0];
        this.Column2 = args[1];
        this.Column3 = args[2];
    }
}
and so on.....
```

Called like so:

```
Array[] ar;
int cnt = ar.Count();
MyObjectBase ob = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "MyObject" + cnt);
ob.Initialize(ar);
```

Comment: The "params" probably isn't necessary, but its a pretty generic example to begin with :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public interface IMyObject
{

}

public class MyObject1 : IMyObject
{
  public string Column1 { get; set; }
}
public class MyObject2 : IMyObject
{
  public string Column1 { get; set; }
  public string Column2 { get; set; }
}
public class MyObject3 : IMyObject
{
  public string Column1 { get; set; }
  public string Column2 { get; set; }
  public string Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

Interface IMyObject identifies your classes. Now create dynamically with Reflection...

```
var assemblyTypes = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
var instanceList = new List<IMyObject>();
foreach (Type currentType in assemblyTypes)
{
  if (currentType.GetInterface("IMyObject") == null) 
    continue;

  Console.WriteLine("Found type: {0}", currentType);
  // create instance and add to list
  instanceList.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(currentType) as IMyObject);
}
```

Hope this will help